# Vue conditionally update options of a select input based on the value of previous select input using FormKit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, compare, formkit

I am working on a multistep form in Vue and Formkit. It has four steps:

1. Group Info
2. Practices
3. Locations
4. Providers

Practices, Locations, and Providers are 'repeaters' - where you can add multiple groups of data, creating an array of objects.

```
{
  "formSteps": {
    "groupStep": {
      "fullAddress": {},
      "pointOfContact": {},
      "contractApproval": {}
    },
    "practiceStep": {
      "practices": [
        {
          "name": "test 1",
          "id": "0"
        },
        {
          "name": "test 2",
          "id": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "test 3",
          "id": "2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "locationStep": {
      "locations": [
        {
          "practiceId": "0",
          "name": "ent office",
          "id": "0",
          "emr": {},
          "fullAddress": {},
          "officeManager": {}
        },
        {
          "practiceId": "1",
          "name": "dentist office",
          "id": "1",
          "emr": {},
          "fullAddress": {},
          "officeManager": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    "providerStep": {
      "providers": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "practice": "0",
          "primaryLocation": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the Providers step, there is a "Practice" `select` where the options are created by iterating over `formSteps.practiceStep.practices`.

```
<FormKit
   type="select"
   label="Practice"
   name="practice"
   :id="`provPractice_${index}`"
>
   <option value="" selected disabled>Select a practice...</option>
   <option v-for="(practice, index) in formData.formSteps.practiceStep.practices" :key="index" :value="practice.id">{{ practice.name }}</option>
</FormKit>
<FormKit
   type="select"
   label="Primary Location"
   name="primaryLocation"
   :id="`provPrimaryLocation_${index}`"
   v-model="`provPractice_${index}`.value"
>
   <option value="" selected disabled>Select a location...</option>
   <!-- Dynamically rendered options that match practiceId here -->
</FormKit>
```

Underneath it is a "Primary Location" `select` where the options needs to be dynamically rendered by comparing the value of the option selected in "Practice" to `practiceID` in `formSteps.locationStep.locations`, and if they equal, populate the matching options.

What would be the best way to tackle this?

FormKit documentation offers a [flat, simple example here](https://formkit.link/d2cc703cbccd569841e92779258788df)

```
<script>
const flavors = computed(() => {
  if (formData.value.food === 'Ice Cream') {
    return ['Chocolate', 'Vanilla']
  }
  return ['Pepperoni', 'Cheese']
})
</script>

<template>
  <FormKit type="form" v-model="formData">
    <FormKit
      type="select"
      label="Food"
      name="food"
      :options="['Pizza', 'Ice Cream']"
    />
    <FormKit
      type="select"
      label="Flavor"
      name="flavor"
      :options="flavors"
    />
  </FormKit>
</template>
```

I'm just unsure on how to do something similar with the more complex data in my case.

Comment: In flat,simple example there's another issue when you choose Pizza, then select f.e. Pepperoni then change to Ice Cream in formData there will be {food: Ice Cream, flavor: Pepperoni}, i'm not sure how to clear children select inputs after changing parent select